# Why does binding not work in JS code (QML)?

Tags: javascript, qt, qml

There's a kind of reusable element that have the property of `Rectangle` type:

```
property Item middleRegion: Rectangle {
   color: "grey";
   border.width: 1;
   height: line.height;
   parent: line
}
```

Then, if an user defines own `middleRegion`, `onMiddleRegionChanged()` is called:

```
onMiddleRegionChanged: {
    middleRegion.parent = line
    middleRegion.height = line.height
}
```

But, despite of the fact that `line.height` is changed, `middleRegion.height` isn't changed after it. Why does binding not work in this code?

The important thing that if user doesn't defined `middleRegion`, everything's going well.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer by myself.

According to the example from [Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-propertybinding.html) the problem is solved by using `Qt.binding()`:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
    width: 100
    height: width * 2

    focus: true
    Keys.onSpacePressed: {
        height = Qt.binding(function() { return width * 3 })
    }
}
```